# Objective-c (Mac) prevent window from opening again

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ibaction, nsbutton

I'm using Shared User Defaults to record a checkbox action if it's marked or not marked. With that I'm trying to have that checkbox set a window to be closed if the checkbox is selected. If not, the window appears.

Tried setting an IBAction for an NSButton with an if and else statement, but it fell through. Any thoughts or ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Need some code to help you out.. Are you sure you're writing to the defaults properly? You need to call the `synchronize` method or it won't actually save your changes.

Comment: @TejaswiYerukalapudi: if he's using an `NSUserDefaultsController` and bindings on Mac OS X, then there doesn't necessarily have to be any code. Also, there's rarely a need to call `synchronize` manually...

Comment: @NSGod It's saving the changes, but I'm doing the defaults like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3783094/Screenshot%202014-04-30%2013.29.19.png

Comment: Oh sorry, I just read that as Standard user defaults and assumed it was `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: @TejaswiYerukalapudi Ahh okay, sorry my bad! Other than that for code, I have a NSButton that self closes and releases the window. I'm looking for a way that the button, once checked, closes the widow every time you launch the app.

Comment: @Pxlc: so the state of a checkbox in one window controls the visible state of a second window directly? If the checkbox is unchecked, the window is hidden, and if the user checks the checkbox, the window should immediately be shown? Or you simply want to prevent the window from being shown on subsequent launches if the user has chosen to uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: @NSGod The checkbox is in the same window it closes. And yes, it should prevent the widow from being shown on subsequent launches if the user has checked the box and shown if the user has the box unchecked. the purpose of the window is to give the user a tour of the app and then once they finish the tour they have the option to make it go away, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3783094/Screenshot%202014-04-30%2013.43.15.png

Answer (score 0):

In the nib file for the window that should be shown or hidden, there is a checkbox for the window properties to be "Visible at Launch". By default, I believe that flag is set, which will automatically cause the window to be shown when the nib file is loaded.

If you want to be selective about whether that window should be shown at launch, you should uncheck the "Visible at Launch" checkbox so that you can choose to show it at your leisure.

What I would do is the following. Assuming `tourWindow` is an `IBOutlet` to the tour window, uncheck the "Visible at Launch" property for that window. I assume if `shouldRunCl` is true, the window should be shown? Your checkbox is worded "Prevent from opening again", so you should bind the checkbox's value to `values.shouldRunCl` with an `NSNegateBoolean` value transformer. Then, in your controller class, do the following:

```
@implementation MDAppController

+ (void)initialize {
    NSMutableDictionary *defaults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [defaults setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"shouldRunCl"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaults];
    [[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController]
                                     setInitialValues:defaults];
}


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                    objectForKey:@"shouldRunCl"] boolValue]) {
        [self.tourWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

The first line in the `+initialize` code sets the default values for `NSUserDefaults` and the initial values of the `NSUserDefaultsController`. That means that in later code you can always count on a value being present when you call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"shouldRunCl"]`. Note that setting it to yes here only sets the default value, it doesn't prevent the user from changing that value when they click the checkbox (hence the name "user defaults").

While I chose `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` to implement the code to show the window, you could also put in `awakeFromNib` or willFinishLaunching. The code checks to see if `shouldRunCl` == `YES`, and if so, shows the `tourWindow`.

There shouldn't be any need to set an `IBAction` for the checkbox; when the user clicks it, it will change (override) the default value for `shouldRunCl` and persist for the next launch.

Comment: Ahh okay I see what's happening. Essentially the user defaults depends on whether the window is open or not? Could I share with you what I have so far? Everything compiles, but I'm still unable to get the window to stay closed.